# Issue with jQuery countdown timer

Tags: jquery, html, countdowntimer

I'm working with timers  when I click the button timer starts from 5 seconds and fadesout when it comes to 0. I tried but couldnt get , here is the fiddle I've tried: http://jsfiddle.net/GNrUM/937/

```
<div id="hideMsg" style="display:none;">
This Box will Close In <span>5</span> Seconds..</div>
<input id="take" type="button"  value="click me" >
```

jQuery code :

```
$("#take").live("click", function () {
    $('#hideMsg').show();
    var sec = $('#hideMsg span').text()
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        $('#hideMsg span').text(--sec);
        if (sec == 0) {
            $('#hideMsg').fadeOut('fast');
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

It's working good for first click, when click 2 time count starts from 0,-1,-2,. It does not clear the intervals. any help?

Comment: try to re-initialize `$('#hideMsg span')` . like `$('#hideMsg span').text('5');`
http://jsfiddle.net/GNrUM/941/

Comment: keep going .. njoy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to re-initialize `$('#hideMsg span')` . like `$('#hideMsg span').text('5');`

http://jsfiddle.net/GNrUM/941

Answer (score 1):

you have to reset the value once it fades out

```
 $('#hideMsg span').text(5);
```

JS Fiddle Demo [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GNrUM/943/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $("#take").live("click",function(){  
    $('#hideMsg').show();    
    var sec = $('#hideMsg span').text()
    var timer = setInterval(function() { 
       $('#hideMsg span').text(--sec);
       if (sec == 0) {
          $('#hideMsg').fadeOut('fast');
           $('#hideMsg span').text("5"); // reinitialize the span value
          clearInterval(timer);
       } 
    }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: Better to do in callback method of fadeout. like `$('#hideMsg').fadeOut('fast',function(){
           $('#hideMsg span').text(5);
       });`